# How to install new font to Kindle 5.6.5

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, fonts

I have bought an Kindle paperwhite with version 5.6.5 and I want to know how to install new fonts to my device. I have seen that previously it was possible to just copy paste the font with a file and restart the device will install the font. But now it is not working. I have to read non-English book but kindle don't support it. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your Kindle was previously jailbroken, you can't install new fonts. If it was, you'll have to re-install the font hack.

> have to read non-English book but kindle don't support it.

Kindles with the 5.6.5 firmware support pretty much all languages without additional fonts. However, you must convert your books to the AZW3 format with [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download), because the old MOBI format doesn't fully support some less frequently spoken languages.
If you don't like the default font, you can also embed fonts in your ebooks with Calibre. For more information see the Calibre documentation.